# Unable to train LSTM model (ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:)

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, multilabel-classification

I am getting this error for LSTM model.
data has three columns

1. Sentence (input)
2. Value (output)
3. Label (output)
   I am using tensorflow2.3.0. I have tried 2.0.0 as suggested but I am landing up with dependency errors.

Please help me resolve this error below in quotes

"ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:

x sizes: 720

y sizes: 89

Please provide data which shares the same first dimension."

```
### Create sequence
vocab_size = 20000
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words= vocab_size)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['Sentence'])
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['Sentence'])
data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=100)

le = LabelEncoder()

df['label'] = le.fit_transform(df['label'])

X = df['Sentence']
y = df[['value','label']]


X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1)

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)

X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)

vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

maxlen = 200

X_train = pad_sequences(X_train, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
X_test = pad_sequences(X_test, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)


#print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 128))
model.add(LSTM(128, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3,batch_size=8, validation_split=0.1)
accr = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('Test set\n  Loss: {:0.3f}\n  Accuracy: {:0.3f}'.format(accr[0], accr[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data has two outputs (the Value and Label columns). But your model has only one output.

This code works:

```
X_train = tf.random.uniform([100, 100], 0, 100, dtype=tf.int32)
y_train = tf.random.uniform([100, 2])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3,batch_size=8, validation_split=0.1)
```

Check the shape of y_train. It should be [batch_size, 2].